# Is this mixed conditional used correctly? “What would you have done if you inherited a large amount of money?”

Tags: american-english

I am an English teacher abroad. Few days ago I used a structure to make a mixed conditional question.
I was told the sentence was incorrect as the condition is in the present while the effect is in the past. However, in my opinion the condition is hypothetical and therefore has no bearing on the past.
The sentence was “what would you have done if you inherited a large amount of money?”
If + past simple >> would have + past participle.

Could you please clarify?

Comment: Please explain why you want to ask about *“What would you **have done** if you **inherited** a large amount of money?”* rather than *“What would you **do** if you **inherited** a large amount of money?”* If you can't answer that, I suggest you stick with my simpler phrasing. Nobody really wants to get bogged down with *“What would you **have done** if you **had inherited** a large amount of money?”* As ever - avoid unnecessary Perfect forms!

Comment: If you use "have done", you should use "had inherited".

Comment: I think What would you do now (or would you be doing now) if you had inherited a large amount of money when ... died? would be a better example of mixed conditionals.